# Set the value of an input field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I put the snippet on the post to show it and it worked normally, now I'm even more confused rsrsr. Does anyone know what details can make this go wrong?

```js
// Questions
var question1 = document.getElementById('1');
    
    
// Answers    
var answer1 = "";


// Results
var result1 = document.getElementById('result-1');

function next1(){
    answer1 = document.getElementById('answer1').value;
    question1.style.display = 'none';
    result1.style.display = 'block';
    
    if(answer1 != ""){
        document.getElementById('result-1-go').value = answer1;
    };
};
```

```html
  <section id="1" style="display: block;">
      <form onsubmit="next1(); return false">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="top">
              </div>
              <div class="question-title">
                  <h2>Name</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="question-input">
                  <input autofocus type="text" id="answer1" class="input-field" required>
              </div>
              <div class="submit-button">
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
  </section>
  
  
  <div id="result-1" class="result-item" style="display: none;">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <input type="text" id="result-1-go" name="result-1-go">
  </div>
```

I'm trying to set a value to an input when a functions runs, but instead it looks like this function is putting html text in the input. What is wrong?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="result-1" class="result-item" style="display: none;">
  <h4>Name</h4>
  <input type="text" id="result-1-go" name="result-1-go">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if(answer1 != ""){
  document.getElementById('result-1').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('result-1-go').value = "Test";
};
```

Result:

```
<div id="result-1" class="result-item" style="display: none;">
  <h4>Name</h4>
  <input type="text" id="result-1-go" name="result-1-go">Test</input>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre] reproducing your issue? Preferably using a [code-snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Yes, it worked here. But in mine it doesn't work. Could it be something wrong with the other variables?